# How to quickly open a split anaconda prompt window using windows keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: terminal, anaconda

I recently started working with anaconda prompt and feel that often times you need to open a seperate prompt window while one is running(say, for hosting a jupyter notebook)

Anyone knows any shortcuts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To open anaconda prompt:

Go with the mouse to the Windows Icon (lower left) and start typing "Anaconda". There should show up some matching entries. Select "Anaconda Prompt". A new command window, named "Anaconda Prompt" will open. Now, you can work from there with Python, conda and other tools.

To open another separate anaconda prompt:
Using auto hotkey bind.